# Oracle:Delete duplicate records in bulk

Tags: oracle11g

I have a table where there are 1220200 duplicate records present.

I'm using below query to delete duplicate records.

```
DELETE /*+ NO_CPU_COSTING  */
  FROM  FCST f1
  WHERE
       ROWID >
           (SELECT MIN (ROWID)
              FROM FCST f2
             WHERE 
                  f1.DMDUNIT = f2.DMDUNIT
                   AND f1.DMDGROUP = f2.DMDGROUP
                   AND f1.LOC = f2.LOC
                   AND f1.STARTDATE = f2.STARTDATE
                   AND f1.TYPE = f2.TYPE
                   AND UPPER (f1.FCSTID) = UPPER (f2.FCSTID));
```

It's taking almost 2 minutes to delete these records. I tried bulk delete approach as well by loading duplicate data into cursor and deleting it in bulk but it is taking more time.

What is better approach to optimize this code?

Comment: Does it really matter?  You are only going to do this once surely, and 2 minutes to remove 1.2 million duplicates seems pretty reasonable.

Comment: Hi Tony,Thanks for the quick response.This is part of migration and it will be executed every time while setting up of new database from sample dump.

Comment: Apart from solution I'm more interested to understand is it possible to optimize it using types,bulk collect or may be parallel pl/sql?

Answer (score 1):

A simple thing to do is something like this

```
delete /*+RULE*/ from t
where rowid in ( select rid
                   from ( select rowid rid,
                                 row_number() over
                                   (partition by cust_seg_nbr order by rowid) rn
                            from t
                        )
                 where rn <> 1 );
```

But then if you have huge data then

Check this link http://www.rampant-books.com/t_stoever_delete_duplicates.htm or use the code below

```
 DECLARE     -- Code ©2004 by Edward Stoever
   CURSOR c_get_duplicates
   IS
      SELECT   ssrfees_term_code, ssrfees_crn, ssrfees_detl_code,
               ssrfees_ftyp_code, ssrfees_levl_code, COUNT (*)
          FROM ssrfees
        HAVING COUNT (*) > 1
      GROUP BY ssrfees_term_code,
               ssrfees_crn,
               ssrfees_detl_code,
               ssrfees_ftyp_code,
               ssrfees_levl_code;

   var_get_duplicates c_get_duplicates%ROWTYPE;

   CURSOR c_del_only_one
   IS
      SELECT ROWID
        FROM ssrfees
       WHERE ssrfees_term_code = var_get_duplicates.ssrfees_term_code
         AND ssrfees_crn = var_get_duplicates.ssrfees_crn
         AND ssrfees_detl_code = var_get_duplicates.ssrfees_detl_code
         AND NVL(ssrfees_ftyp_code,'1') = NVL(var_get_duplicates.ssrfees_ftyp_code,'1')
         AND NVL(ssrfees_levl_code,'1') = NVL(var_get_duplicates.ssrfees_levl_code,'1');

   var_del_only_one ROWID;
BEGIN
   OPEN c_get_duplicates;

   LOOP
      FETCH c_get_duplicates
       INTO var_get_duplicates;

      EXIT WHEN c_get_duplicates%NOTFOUND;

      OPEN c_del_only_one;

      FETCH c_del_only_one
       INTO var_del_only_one;

      DELETE FROM ssrfees
            WHERE ROWID = var_del_only_one;

      COMMIT;

      CLOSE c_del_only_one;
   END LOOP;

   CLOSE c_get_duplicates;
END;
/
```

Comment: If you have huge amounts of data then I'd suspect that the last approach you'd want would be one with nested cursors, particularly when a commit is included. This looks like a recipe for poor performance.

Answer (score 0):

A query containing "ROWID > ..." is fundamentally suspect.

I think that what you're looking for is this:

```
DELETE FROM
  FCST f1
WHERE
  ROWID NOT IN (
    SELECT   MIN(ROWID)
    FROM     FCST f2
    GROUP BY f2.DMDUNIT,
             f2.DMDGROUP,
             f2.LOC,
             f2.STARTDATE,
             f2.TYPE,
             UPPER(f2.FCSTID));
```

The subquery identifies a set of ROWID's that cover all of the unique values for the columns in the GROUP BY clause, and all others are deleted.

A faster alternative might be to create a new table with just the rows that are to be kept, but if this is performant enough then stick with this.